# What is the command used in Linux to know info about memory interleaving?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel, sysfs

I am working on the Linux Kernel as part of my course homework and this is the information I seek:

In the latest systems, memory is split up into ranks under which which memory is interleaved among the different ranks in a non-contiguous way. This was implemented to increase the speed of processor in accessing the memory. I would like to know if there is any command in Linux which when executed gives us any information about how the memory is being split up into ranks. I have tried using the following command

```
    sudo dmidecode --type memory
```

but the above command showed information about hardware but not whether memory is being interleaved or not. Could anyone please let me know if there is any command that can show me such info? If such command doesn't exist, could you please let me know which part of the code I can refer for the implementation of memory interleaving in Linux Kernel?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to read memory control's higher bit address decoding schedule ? As in memory interleaving, the higher address bit is decoded in non-sequencial order.

Answer (score 0):

if bios setup smbios structure correctly, you should able to figure out interleaving setting from DMI type 20 (Memory Device mapped Address) structure. E.g For 4 way interleaving case, DIMM 0 of channel 0, 1, 2, 3 should have same mapped address.

Comment: Is there anything that can be interpreted ( in this respect .. interleaving )
  by looking at Type **19** ( `Memory Array Mapped Address` ) ?
For example,
```Handle 0x0032, DMI type 19, 31 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
        Starting Address: 0x00000000000
        Ending Address: 0x17FFFFFFFFF
        Range Size: 1536 GB
        Physical Array Handle: 0x0031
        Partition Width: 24```